# Detectar Led de Notificaciones Android Studio

Tags: android, push-notification, android-notifications, notificaciones

Tengo una simple duda, estoy programando notificaciones, y me doy cuenta que cuando involucro la linea de codigo:

```
.setLights(Color.GREEN, 3000, 3000)
```

Aparece errores en celulares que no tienen el LED de notificaciones(como celulares con android 4.1.1), así que me preguntaba si hay algún método para saber si el celular donde se esta ejecutando la aplicación detecte si tiene o no este famoso LED de notificaciones para asi indicar:
Si tiene el LED entonces que haga la linea de codigo:

```
.setLights(Color.GREEN, 3000, 3000)
```

Si no tiene el LED entonces que no haga esa linea de codigo

Comment: Aun no hay ningun soporte que permita hacer esto: [https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36956842](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36956842)

Comment: prueba de englobar en un try catch cambiar el color y que la función devuelva true or false, para luego puedas personalizar

Comment: No exista algún método u API para realizar esta comprobación @LuisOlazo

Comment: Muchas Gracias por Responder :)

Answer (score 1):

#### Como detectar si el dispositivo soporta mostrar colores mediante el LED.

**Actualmente (Android 8.1) no existe una API para detectar si el dispositivo puede o no mostrar colores mediante el LED cuando mostramos notificaciones.**

---

#### Como detectar si el dispositivo soporta vibrar.

Si tu dispositivo soporta vibración puedes detectarla mediante la clase [**Vibrator**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Vibrator):

```
Vibrator mVibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        boolean hasVibrator = mVibrator != null && mVibrator.hasVibrator();
        if(hasVibrator) {
           // Muestra notificación with vibration.
        }else{
           //Muestra notificación sin vibración.
        }
```

Actualmente me parece que los últimos sistemas operativos no requieren el permiso, pero te aconsejo agregues `android:required="false"` para que tu aplicación en la Play Store no filtre tu aplicación para dispositivos que no soporten vibración.

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" android:required="false"/>
```

Comment: pero preguntaba por led (cara de duda)

Comment: @gbianchi agregué como plus lo relacionado a la vibración.

Comment: ahora si esta mucho mejor ;)

Comment: Buena informacion lo de la vibracion y los permisos para que no lo filtre google(no lo sabia), pero es cierto preguntaba sobre el problema del LED. Estaba leyendo por foros similes y dicen que no han soporte para eso; si alguno consigue la respuesta definitiva estaria agradecido :)